# How do I ignore files from a Visual Studio 2017 solution items folder?

Tags: c#

I have some exported SQL files that are just there for recordkeeping, but they're not something I want to compiler to throw errors on. They're in the Solution Items folder.

[image: An image showing the files throwing compiler errors]

The SQL files are making it so my program can't compile. I've read about the Build Action ignore, but when I try to select the properties of those files, or this folder, I can't find how to ignore these files from the compiler anywhere.

Also, I'm pretty new to a lot of this, so in depth explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Select the file, press F4, you should see a properties window. Under Advanced -> Build Action click Compile and change it to None

Comment: Maybe you want this : Right Click > Exclude From Project

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich that's what I've been reading, but once I'm in properties there is no "Advanced" section". 

you can see the properties list here, am I missing something?https://imgur.com/a/ksr4chz

Comment: @Shim-Sao I want these files to be posted to the repo, but not compiled. Excluding them from the project would mean they would no longer be tracked by Git right? Thus no longer tracked by the repo?

Comment: No they will not be part of the project but still in the directory. Git and Visual Studio are not the same things.

Comment: On the top of the list there is button to show/hide files that are not part of the project and you can add file you want (reverse)

Comment: @Shim-Sao so there's no way to tell the compiler to ignore the .SQL files though?

Comment: You can change action generation in the properties of a file. But exclude is not a problem, Git is a monitor : you can make a branch with a file in the project and exclude it in another branch.

Comment: Why is the compiler looking to compile those files? They're at the solution level, it shouldn't care. What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: To ignore files in Git it's in .gitignore or in .git/info/exclude (local) . It's why Visual Studio and Git is not the same thing.

Comment: I don't know, I have try to add sql and for me by default action generation is on content. Maybe yours are in compile instead of content. But if your files are not content of the application (no need to copy them) and are just here for you, exclude them.